# Как передать ArrayList<String> через intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

(Android) Как передать `ArrayList<String>` через intent и как его получить в следующем активити?

UPD

Кладем в Intent :

```
public void get_masterList() {
        ...
        final String sferaOption;
        final ArrayList<String> midList = new ArrayList<>();

            ...

        ...

        lvCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tvMid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMid);
                String mid = tvMid.getText().toString();

                // Передаем  id мастера в следующий Активити
                Intent intent = new Intent(catalog_activity.this, masterDetails2.class);
                intent.putExtra("mid", mid);
                intent.putExtra("sferaOption", sferaOption);
                intent.putExtra("midlist", midList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Проверял через Debug - midList содержит 3 элемента

Получаем в следующей активити:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_master_details2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_title));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        final String mid, sferaOption;
        ArrayList<String> midList;

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            mid = null;
            sferaOption = null;
            midList = null;
        } else {
            mid = extras.getString("mid");
            sferaOption = extras.getString("sferaOption");

        }

            midList =  (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("midList");

        Toast.makeText(this, midList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Приложение закрывается с ошибкой, через Debug видим midList = null

Comment: `putStringArrayListExtra()`/`getStringArrayListExtra()`

Comment: Пробовалось. Всё пустое..

Comment: Вы кладете `midlist`, а ищите `midList`. Регистр имеет значение. Пользуйтесь константами.

Comment: Да, простите, проглядел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кладём лист в `intent` в `FirstActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActvity.class);
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.add("some text");
    intent.putExtra("list", array);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Достаем лист из `intent` в `SecondActivity.java`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> arrayFromIntent = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
    }
```

Comment: getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list") - это чему-нибудь присваивается? или как с этим дальше работать?

Comment: ну у вас задача передать из одной активити в другую, т.е. вы создаете интент и ложите в него ArrayList и с этим интентом вызываете второе активити, после этого в другом активити из входящего интента достаете ArrayList который вы упаковали в интент в первом активити

Comment: Вот так у меня и было // Передаем  id мастера в следующий Активити
                Intent intent = new Intent(catalog_activity.this, masterDetails2.class);
                intent.putExtra("mid", mid);
                intent.putExtra("sferaOption", sferaOption);
                intent.putExtra("midlist", midList);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: Но на приеме как ни принимаю midList = null

Comment: кстати ArrayList<String> arrayFromIntent = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list"); так тоже midList = null

Comment: показывайте свой код

Comment: Добавил к вопросу

Comment: я изменил ваш код в вопросе, попробуйте так

Comment: Только вынесли midList =  (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("midList"); эту строчку из условия?

Comment: да, но вобще у вас там во всем блоке по-ходу ошибка, попробуйте так как я написал сделать

Comment: midList = null . Не думаю что вынос из условия мог что либо изменить..

Comment: extras чему равно?  null ?

Comment: Нет. После выполнения условия и mid, и sferaOption получают свои значения. Вот midList как заколдованный..

Comment: Странно, потому что у меня код работатет!

Comment: Я добавил в ответ  100% рабочий код. Можете скопировать себе попробовать, после чего я удалю ответ ато некомпетентные люди минусуют.

Comment: @KirillStoianov Вас -2 репутации настолько испугали?

Comment: щас еще какой нибудь знаток зайдет поминусовать правильный ответ

Comment: @YuraIvanov ответ от этого не становится неправильным